# passing jquery selector as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, selector

[image]I Want to pass a jquery selector to a function but it didn't work , what is the problem ?

```
$(".university .seeMap").one("click",function(){
    HideMap($(this));
});
function ShowMap(element){
    $(element).html('See The Map &nbsp; <i class="zmdi zmdi-pin"></i>');
    $(element).one("click",HideMap(element));
    $(element).next(".university-map").fadeOutn();
}
function HideMap(element){
    $(element).html('Hide The Map &nbsp; <i class="zmdi zmdi-pin"></i>');
    $(element).one("click",ShowMap(element));
    $(element).next(".university-map").fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: أهلا بأخي عبد الله .. 
Add `alert('click fire')` before `HideMap($(this))` , and tell me what give you when you click

Comment: أهلا بك أخى يظهر الاليرت بعد كده تظهر الصورة الموجوده فى السؤال

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI and Abdallah: Guys, it may seem harmless, but **please stick to English on-site**. Comments are meant to be intelligible to all.

Comment: comments can be in english ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI: :-) Comments *must* be in English (as the majority of your comment was).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing a *selector*, you're passing a jQuery instance.

The problem is that `$(element).one("click",ShowMap(element));` **calls** `ShowMap(element)` and passes its return value into `one`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

Since you're calling them immediately, your code crashes the browser because `HideMap` calls `ShowMap` which calls `HideMap` which calls `ShowMap`...forever until you get *(drum roll please)* a **stack overflow**.

If you want to "bake" an argument into a function, you can use `Function#bind` or jQuery's own `$.proxy`:

```
$(element).one("click",HideMap.bind(null, element));
// ---------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
$(element).one("click",$.proxy(HideMap, null, element));
// --------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In both cases, they create a new function that, when called, will call the original with the given `this` value (you're not using `this`, so I've used `null` above<sup>1</sup>) along with any arguments you supply to `bind`/`proxy`.

---

<sup>1</sup> When you use `null` for the `thisArg` argument, the function will either be called with `null` (in strict mode) or with a reference to the global object (in loose mode).

---

Side note: You're repeatedly re-wrapping the element, running it through `$()` over and over again for no reason. It's harmless, but pointless.

Instead, I suggest writing `ShowMap` and `HideMap` such that they expect the element to *already* be wrapped:

```
$(".university .seeMap").one("click",function(){
    HideMap($(this));
});
function ShowMap(element){
    element.html('See The Map &nbsp; <i class="zmdi zmdi-pin"></i>');
    element.one("click",HideMap.bind(null, element));
    element.next(".university-map").fadeOutn();
}
function HideMap(element){
    element.html('Hide The Map &nbsp; <i class="zmdi zmdi-pin"></i>');
    element.one("click",ShowMap.bind(null, element));
    element.next(".university-map").fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: ...(drum roll please) a <b>stack overflow</b>. +1  :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry I don't know what are you mean with OP's acceptance bro but thanks alot anyway , your answer is very useful for me

Answer (score -1):

As T.J. says, you're passing a jQuery object already. So you can very simply just stop trying to turn "element" into one. Like this:

```
$(".university .seeMap").one("click",function(){
    HideMap($(this));
});
function ShowMap(element){
    element.html('See The Map &nbsp; <i class="zmdi zmdi-pin"></i>');
    element.one("click",HideMap(element));
    element.next(".university-map").fadeOutn();
}
function HideMap(element){
    element.html('Hide The Map &nbsp; <i class="zmdi zmdi-pin"></i>');
    element.one("click",ShowMap(element));
    element.next(".university-map").fadeIn();
}
```

**But this version still crashes the browser.** So keep reading:

As for what you are doing with adding the click event showmap/hidemap each time. I think there is a better way to do it. It seems that you are trying to use the same element to either show the map or hide the map. I would suggest this:

```
$(".university .seeMap").on("click",function(){
    toggleMap($(this));
});

function toggleMap(element) {
    if (element.is(":visible")){
        element.next(".university-map").fadeOut();
        element.html('Show The Map &nbsp; <i class="zmdi zmdi-pin"></i>');
    }else {
        element.next(".university-map").fadeIn();
        element.html('Hide The Map &nbsp; <i class="zmdi zmdi-pin"></i>');
    }
}
```